# Does Magento 2 always transliterate product url keys or only when generating it?

Tags: magento2, product, url, url-key

In our Magento 2.2.9 shop when updating a products url_key it has been transliterated automatically to remove spaces, umlauts, etc.. We now updated to 2.3.3 and this behavior stopped working.

I checked with vanilla 2.2.9 and 2.3.3 instances and when updating a url_key for a product it is not transliterated. So it seems this has never been a feature of Magento but we do not recall implementing such a feature.

I do know Magento transliterates the url_key when generating it based on the product name but has it ever been (or is) a feature of Magento that the url_key is always transliterated e.g. when updating or saving it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Magento versions 2.2.9 and 2.3.3 Magento did always transliterate the url keys of products, whenever the event `catalog_product_save_before` was called. The responsible code can be found [here (observer)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7aa94564d85e408baea01abc5315a0441401c375/app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/Observer/ProductUrlKeyAutogeneratorObserver.php#L36) and [here (here the transliteration is called)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ddf42caaf25311f10b23b95a92746f99943e045e/app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/Model/ProductUrlPathGenerator.php#L138).

In this [commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6f4f511822fbbcb743a7d4a8de6353d207d99429#diff-386b1042295a816ae69d1e2988756f82L138) it has been changed and it only transliterates the url key if it's not null. If you save a product with a url key, e.g. when you want to update it, it will not be transliterated.

In my opinion this is a bug so I opened an [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26499) on github.